# How to active application for video calling or chat using Quickblox iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, background-process, quickblox

I heard about iOS it self wouldn't allow an app to stay longer while its in background. I don't know exact minutes but how I can active my app to handle video / audio calls or for chat functionality. I'm using Quickblox iOS SDK for video/audio calls and chatting.

P.S. I've successfully implemented this functionality only worry about background? Is there a way in Quickblox SDK to achieve this?

Any help/suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: did you got any solution?. please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of the application where you can perform actions or keep alive your app while your app is in background.

**Audio and AirPlay**

The app plays audible content to the user or records audio while in the background. (This content includes streaming audio or video content using AirPlay.)
The user must grant permission for apps to use the microphone prior to the first use; for more information, see Supporting User Privacy.

**Location updates**

The app keeps users informed of their location, even while it is running in the background.

**Voice over IP**

The app provides the ability for the user to make phone calls using an Internet connection

**Newsstand downloads**

The app is a Newsstand app that downloads and processes magazine or newspaper content in the background.

External accessory communication
The app works with a hardware accessory that needs to deliver updates on a regular schedule through the External Accessory framework.

**Uses Bluetooth LE accessories**

The app works with a Bluetooth accessory that needs to deliver updates on a regular schedule through the Core Bluetooth framework.

**Acts as a Bluetooth LE accessory**

The app supports Bluetooth communication in peripheral mode through the Core Bluetooth framework.
Using this mode requires user authorization; for more information, see Supporting User Privacy.

**Background fetch**

The app regularly downloads and processes small amounts of content from the network.

**Remote notifications**

The app wants to start downloading content when a push notification arrives. Use this notification to minimize the delay in showing content related to the push notification.

If your app will be performing one of the above tasks just add related key into your plist file. For more check official Apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html